# Strongly-typed layout and strongly-typed page which wants to use it

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem with architecture and passing models in my Asp.NET MVC app...
Here's the thing.

I created strongly-typed layout, because I have login panel inside layout (as a partial view), which needs his model.
And now I have some views (registration and contact page), which use this layout and I don't know how to pass them their models...

My question is how to solve that problem e.g. by another constructing, but possibly without doubling a code. Building ViewModel with all possible Models for pages which used this Layout doesn't look like an option (even if there is some way to pass model further to @RenderBody()).

**My code**

**Login panel (partial view)**

```
@model Models.Home.LoginModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "login" }))
{
    //some form fields here
}
```

**Layout**

```
@model Models.Home.LoginModel
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html&gt;
&lt;head&gt;
&lt;/head&gt;
&lt;body&gt;
    &lt;div id="login"&gt;
        @Html.Partial("Account/_Login", @Model)
    &lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div id="main"&gt;
        @RenderBody()
    &lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/body&gt;
```

**Page**

```
@model Models.Home.RegisterModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Registration";
}
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "registerDialog" }))
{
    //some form fields here
}
```

**Controller action for Login**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView("Account/_Login", model);
    }
    else
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**Controller action for Register**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel registerModel)
{
    return View(registerModel);
}
```

I simplified everything by removing unnecessary lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this without repeating code would probably be to implement your login logic using a Child Action (instead of a partial view).

Child Actions are like partial views but they also have their own controller method which can be used to load all the model that the partial view requires.

An example:

**Controller**

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Login() {
     LoginModel model;
     // do login check, set model
     return View("_Login", model);
}
```

**Layout**

```
<body>
<div class="header">@Html.Action("Login")</div>
@RenderBody()
</body>
```

**_Login.cshtml**

```
@model LoginModel
@if(Model.IsLoggedIn) {
    <text>Welcome @Model.UserName</text>
} else {
    .. do ajax form stuff here ...
}
```

Comment: Do you have any example? Not really know what you mean. ChildActionOnly attribute? Or RenderAction? One way or another I still need controller action for Login work like I wrote (for not AJAX request it returns View with model). I think there is no way to do this without big ViewModel which handle all Models? ;>

Comment: About above - I don't need to return View with model, I only need that working without javascript (validation and so on...).

Comment: Thx for example, I tried that but as I thought it doesn't work without javascript enabled - I still need additional Post method Login(LoginModel model) and there I can only return that PartialView. Am I missing something? ;)

Comment: Sure, you might need more logic and web endpoints. What's unclear is your question. Are you asking how to avoid passing view models from views to layouts to partial views? Or are you asking how to implement Ajax-based login on a website?

Comment: Ajax-based which could also work without javascript and that makes it a little more difficult ;) Thanks for your help, knowledge about child action may be helpful one day, but know I end up with ViewModel which contains RegisterModel, LoginModel and ContactModel and I think that nothing more can be done with that if I want to work that without javascript almost the same like with it (with layout and so on...).